Docker mosquitto Adress not available
I try to build a docker-compose for mosquitto and node red, but no matter what i do, i always get the same error from mosquitto.
mosq  | 1716134494: Error: Address not available
i even tried to minimize the configurations in the compose file to
version: '3.8'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    container_name: mosq
    ports:
      - 1883:1883

and still int wont work.
I checked to exit all my other containers, even if none of them use the same port.

This suggests that something else on your host is listening on port 1883. What is the output of sudo ss -tlnp | grep 1883?

Is mosquitto running on the host?

This issue and the answers to this question may help (basically you need a mosquitto.conf with a listener).

You need to add this to your mosquitto.conf
listener 1883

Details can be found here https://mosquitto.org/documentation/migrating-to-2-0/
version: '3.8'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    container_name: mosq
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf

You will see something like this
mosq  | mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
mosq  | Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
mosq  | Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
mosq  | Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
mosq  | mosquitto version 2.0.18 running


and port will be open on 1883 for more configuration options I suggest you to check https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/mosquitto.conf

I already had the config and path description for the volume. But thanks to you I double checked it and realised that I accidently saved the config as mosquitto.config instead of mosquitto.conf
